# VSCode. OmniSharp do not load right solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

In my work project, navigation is not working.

Folder that I need to open in VSCode is: `c:\repoSVN\prj_ai_prjs_rc\`. Solution that I want to load is: `c:\repoSVN\prj_ai_prjs_rc\implementation\KRN\KRN.sln`

When I see OmniSharp logs, I see that it loads wrong solution:

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 2017-11-27 09:57:44
Target: c:\repoSVN\prj_ai_prjs_rc\.build\02_Aure.Product.sln
```

No errors. Just loading solution and its projects.
And there is nothing about `KRN.sln`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [VSCode documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp#_roslyn-and-omnisharp):
When omnisharp is loaded right click its icon in the status bar and choose change projects, from there you can manually select your solution file.

Comment: Alternatively, if the project icon does not show up in the status bar, you can do the same from the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), by choosing _OmniSharp: Select Project_.