# VSCode cannot find symbols - No matching workspace symbols

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnisharp

When I search for some method names in CTRL+T (Command+T) it fails to find methods that are open in the editor. See comments under screenshots below.

[image: Partial screenshot showing method name searched for, error, and the actual method]

Above shows the method I'm trying to find and the failure to locate it by the tool.

[image: Partial screenshot showing Go to Symbol feature no seeing any editor symbols]

And above, when I use "Go to Symbol" I'd expect to see a list of symbols.

I'm using macOS Monterey and recently updated and installed tooling. Edit: I should point out that this codebase is recently on .NET 6.0.

Is it broken or am I misunderstanding something??

Edit: tagging omnisharp as it's probably something to do with that. Oh and CodeLens reference counters are missing.

Edit: I'm coming to the conclusion that OmniSharp isn't ready for .NET 6 as I can now see in the Output pane for OmniSharp that it has only loaded my one remaining .NET 5 project and ignored all the .NET 6 ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking in the OmniSharp logs very carefully showed it loading my Bot solution, not the solution I wanted to work on, which has a name that comes after Bot.

I didn't realise that VSCode or OmniSharp was solution aware when a workspace file is loaded.

I clicked down in the status bar to choose a different solution file.

[VSCode. OmniSharp do not load right solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505491/vscode-omnisharp-do-not-load-right-solution)